# html dropdown list taking me to the wrong url

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create a drop down list that would take me to the same page but with the value of the last selected option. I got my code to work the first time an item is selected. Once another item is selected, the code direct me to the url/foourl/value instead of foourl/value. Any way to fix this?

```
<select name="DocSelect" onchange="window.location=value" >
@foreach (var x in Model.ListOfDocs)
{
   <option value= "../loandoc/@x.DocumentSetId">@x.DocumentSetName</option>
}
</select>
```

any way to fix this? I tried many approaches to this problem with no luck.

btw, the foreach loop returns select values like this one

```
<option value= "../loandoc/108">example1</option>
<option value= "../loandoc/123">example2</option>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to get to the same *loandoc* page with another value (after slash?), maybe you can try this:

```
<select name="DocSelect" onchange="window.location=this.value">
@foreach (var x in Model.ListOfDocs)
{
   <option value="@x.DocumentSetId">@x.DocumentSetName</option>
}
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks, but my URL I keep losing my controller name from the url (because I have the ../ of course). I changed it and now I am running into my original issue where the redirect works on the first time, but fails on the second try (I got the url /controllername/loandoc/loandoc/898)

Comment: That is really strange. Have you tried to use absolute path? I mean at least to set option values to `/AssetResearch/loandoc/XXX`, or to write `onchange="window.location='/AssetResearch/loandoc/' + this.value"` and set option values to IDs?

Comment: That did it! I think I tried to insert the url before the value before and used double quotes. Thanks a lot.